# Fasting obligatory fast on friday

Tags: sawm, jumuah

Is it ok to fast on Friday alone to make up obligatory Ramadan fasts?

I know we are not supposed to fast on a Friday without fasting on the day before or after, but in the case of making up obligatory days, can i do so?

Comment: Please urgent answer needed; and what if that Friday is A'rafa day